# How much D.E. does this Jacuzzi filter need when it says "3 scoops" on the label?

Tags: pool, hot-tub

This Jacuzzi filter requires "3 scoops" of diatomaceous earth. How much is that in SI units?

[image: Amt. of D.E. Required 3 Scoops]

Comment: How big was the scoop that came with the jacuzzi?

Comment: If the filter has a pressure gauge, after cleaning and with filtration running, add DE premixed with water slowly until filter back pressure has increased 1 PSI.  It’s only painful the first time.because you have to premix the DE slurry about a 1/4 cup  DE at a time., after the first time you will know the correct amount.  Also that filter appears to be Jacuzzi branded, they have a great spa support dept, they help over the phone with any product in or out of warranty.

Comment: @Tyson It does indeed have a pressure gauge. Cup like [this](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/v%C3%A4rdera-teacup-with-saucer-white__09379_pe085867_s5.jpg) or cup like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Simple_Measuring_Cup.jpg)?

Comment: @Chenmunka Actually that was a good hint. There is none, but I found [this](http://www.poolcenter.com/p/de-filter-powder-scoop-42-3541-00) and it says "Easily measure out 1 lb. of DE", so I guess this filter needs about 1360 g of DE. I will confirm that by observing the pressure as suggested by Tyson.

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.traditionaloven.com/conversions_of_measures/scoop-size.html), a **Scoop** = 4 cups (946.35 ml, 32 fl-oz).

Comment: The measuring cup, and use like 1/4 cup at a time.  My guess is that you will use under 1cup.  Not even close to a pound.

Comment: My pool sized filter requires 1 cup (the measuring variety)

Comment: Wow, that seems like a big difference.